# How to forward to a servlet after writing response

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

Is is possible to forward to url after commiting response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because client already received the data as normal (200) response. Redirecting is done through diiferent response status (3xx). Of course, you can set the status of, let's say 302, and add content to that, but client will most likely not show you that content. So, it's either content (200) or redirection (302), not both.